Managed Identity used in Azure Logic App to authenticate to Azure Function
We aim for using managed Identity in Azure Logic App to authenticate to Azure Function but we have a problem with this approach getting 403 Http Status Code.
enter image description here
below our configuration :
We have Azure Logic App that has Actions that call Azure Functions. Before we have secret based authentication but right now we want to abandon using secrets directly in Azure Logic Apps.
Configuration in Azure Function , section Authentication. There is system-assigned managed identity from Logic App set as Application (client) ID according to the guideline no.1. As well there is tenant Id (Entra ID tenant) in Issuer URL. All other configuration were form manual. As well Allowed token audiences was tested value "https://management.azure.com" as well "https://management.azure.com/".
pic 1. configuration of Authentication Identity Provider in the targeted Azure Function (target)
pic 2. managed identity in Azure Logic App (source)
pic 3. permissions for system-assigned managed identity of Azure Logic App
pic 4. configuration of Azure Logic App step to call Azure Function with managed identity.
pic 4. configuration of Azure Logic App step to call Azure Function with managed identity.
So this is all of our configuration. We'd pleased if you spot something we did wrong or something that can fix the issue. All help will be appreciated.
